# Java - getManifest() issue: Not first entry

Tags: java, jar, manifest, manifest.mf

I want to generate programtically a jar file in java. This works well when the input jar file has NOT been obfuscated. When I use an obfuscator on it, the first entry is no longer the manifest, so I can't generate a new file...

Here is my code:

```
JarInputStream input = new JarInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/obfuscated_jar.jar"));
JarOutputStream output = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("generated_jar.jar"), input.getManifest());
```

The line `input.getManifest()` returns null because the manifest is not at the first place.

I've made some searches on it, and it looks to be a known issue with `JarInputStream`. So here is my question: Is it possible to solve it? Like writing my own getManifest method or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to make it.

I saved my file `MANIFEST.MF` into my main jar and used that code to replace the `input.getManifest()`

```
Manifest mf = new Manifest();
mf.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/lib/manifest.mf"));
```

In this case, I extracted the `manifest.mf` from `obfuscated_jar.jar` and paste it into the lib folder of my main jar file.

That's probably not the best way but it works!

I hope this could help someone.